# Forced air duct with pull chain

Tags: hvac

I have an older forced air furnace and on one of the ducts going through the basement ceiling there is a vent that looks like radiator and it has a pull chain in the middle. When I pull on it, it sounds like something is opening or closing. I feel very little air flow coming out in either position. what is it?

Comment: A picture will help.  A high vent might use a pull chain instead of needing a ladder to open/close, but might be broken/duct block some where else.

Comment: Unless you're going to cut open the duct to see what's in there, a picture of a chain hanging out of duct isn't going to help.

Answer (score 5):

Before the automation time ...

A manual chain was used to close/open vents for air flow control.

Inside it looks like window blinds that open close.

Use a flash light and look inside.

Comment: I'd call it a "flow damper".

Comment: and look inside for a broken spring. See picture below. Also, it's called a *louver*.

Comment: "Louvers are a type of damper consisting of several blades mounted parallel across a duct." https://www.globalspec.com/learnmore/building_construction/hvac/ventilation/dampers_louvers - If it's a singular blade it's just *damper*. If it has more than one it's a *louvered damper*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damper_(flow)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

airdistributor.net/p-456-canarm-ltd-brand-fresh-air-drainable-manual-chain-operated-adjustable-wall-louver-12-to-60.aspx

Comment: I get how this is useful and upvoted, as it shows what it is. But it also is not an answer. Just a link and a picture. It is a community wiki answer, so I guess it is the intended format for this site, but it leaves me puzzled. How is this an answer?

Comment: See comment above ;)

Comment: Can't put pictures in comments. What should've happened is an edit to the existing answer as if this was Wikipedia (and I can just do that with my 10k rep), except people get all huffy or w/e, and that's where the SE model fails. It's an answer because it's in the answer box, with *the* single prerequisite of it being there: that it is useful. That I put zero work into this and knowing where it should be, is why it's CW.